# Can I somehow use a different file picker dialog than GNOME/GTK's own?

Tags: gnome, gtk, dialog

I use the Cinnamon desktop environment on my Devuan Daedalus GNU/Linux machine. I like Cinnamon well enough (better than the other DEs available obviously), but - I'm not a fan of GTk, and most especially, the GTk filer picker dialog is absolutely *horrid*. I find it so inconvenient! ... instead of ranting, though, let me be practical: Is there someway I could replace it with something else? e.g. some kind of plugin or LD_PRELOAD trick?

Answer (score 2):

You can't configure the file picker dialog, because Gnome hates configurability. So your only options are to live with it, not use Gnome or more generally GTK applications, or replace the offending code.

To replace the offending code, as you suspect, the way is to use a preloaded library to override the function that opens the GTK file chooser dialog.

1. Write your own library containing an implementation of either `gtk_file_chooser_dialog_new` or `gtk_dialog_run` or some other function (and probably some companion functions as well).
2. Set the environment variable `LD_PRELOAD` to the path to the compiled library (`export LD_PRELOAD=/path/to/mylib.so`, or `LD_PRELOAD=$LD_PRELOAD:/path/to/mylib.so` if the variable is already set) in the environment of all GTK applications (it'll be harmless for non-GTK applications).

Here are two projects to replace the GTK file chooser dialog by the Qt (KDE) file chooser dialog:

- https://gitlab.com/Vogtinator/qtkdialog
- https://github.com/sandsmark/kgtk/tree/master/common

Neither of them is actively maintained. I have used neither. I have not inspected them in any way and cannot vouch for their quality. This post is not an endorsement, only a mention. No liability is expressed or implied. Contents may settle during download.

---

My solution is to live with it, and pretty much my sole interaction with the file chooser dialog is <kbd>Ctrl+L</kbd> to make the location bar appear (ah, for the good old days when you could have it appear by default) and paste a path.

Comment: Well, at least you've taught us about Ctrl+L.

Comment: qtkdialog didn't work for me with Thunderbird/BetterBird. I mean, it built fine, but I still got the GNOME file picker.

Comment: @einsupportsModeratorStrike If you already haven't, you might try prepending the environment variables to however you're launching Thunderbird. "ENV_VAR=option /usr/bin/thunderbird". If you're launching it with an icon or through a software center, you can find the file that configures the icon launcher for that app and add it there. I'm not on a Gnome system now, so I don't remember.

Comment: I believe I did that, but I'll give it another shot.